# SQL Server: Dynamically Pivot Temp Table (Dynamic SQL)

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to Dynamically pivot my `@Tempproj` table. This table consists of multiple CTE's that I insert into this `@Tempproj`. Now I want to Pivot this temptable, however I currently can only do it now when I create a Physical table instead of a Temporary one.

When I run it with the following query it says:
`Must declare the table variable "@Tempproj"`

I don't know how to mix this SQL with Dynamic SQL correctly.

First I declare a temp table, quite a long statement, and all the way below is the Dynamic SQL Pivot query I use.

```
CREATE TABLE #Tempproj
(
       [ProjKey] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Lvl3] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Lvl2] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Lvl1] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Element ID] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Activiteit] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Doel] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Activiteitsnummer] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Begindatum/-tijd] date NULL
       ,[Einddatum/-tijd] date NULL
       ,[Status projectfase] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Afsluitingsdatum/-tijd] date NULL
       ,[Projectactiviteit] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[VerantwoordelijkeId] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Verantwoordelijke] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Categorie] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[Prioriteit] nvarchar(250) NULL
       ,[DataAreaID] nvarchar(250) NULL

);

WITH cteP AS (
       SELECT
              [NAME]
              ,ELEMENTNUMBER
              ,PARENTELEMENTNUMBER
              ,PathID                    = CAST(ELEMENTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(MAX))
              ,DATAAREAID
       FROM   HIERARCHYTREETABLE
       WHERE  NULLIF(PARENTELEMENTNUMBER, '') IS NULL
       UNION  All
       SELECT
              [NAME] = r.[NAME]
              ,ELEMENTNUMBER       = r.ELEMENTNUMBER
              ,PARENTELEMENTNUMBER = r.PARENTELEMENTNUMBER
              ,PathID                    = p.PathID+CONCAT(',',CAST(r.ELEMENTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
              ,DATAAREAID          = r.DATAAREAID
       FROM   HIERARCHYTREETABLE r
       JOIN   cteP p ON r.PARENTELEMENTNUMBER  = p.ELEMENTNUMBER
                 AND r.DATAAREAID = p.DATAAREAID
       )
       ,
cteP2 AS (
SELECT
       B.Lvl3
       ,B.Lvl2
       ,B.Lvl1
       ,HIERARCHYTREETABLE.ELEMENTNUMBER AS 'Element ID'
       ,HIERARCHYTREETABLE.[NAME] AS 'Activiteit'
       ,SMMACTIVITIES.PURPOSE AS 'Doel'
       ,SMMACTIVITIES.ACTIVITYNUMBER AS 'Activiteitsnummer'
       ,SMMACTIVITIES.STARTDATETIME AS 'Begindatum/-tijd'
       ,NULLIF(SMMACTIVITIES.ENDDATETIME, '') AS 'Einddatum/-tijd'
       ,CASE WHEN SMMACTIVITIES.CLOSED = 1 THEN 'Gesloten' ELSE 'Open' END AS 'Status projectfase'
       ,NULLIF(SMMACTIVITIES.ACTUALENDDATETIME, '') AS 'Afsluitingsdatum/-tijd'
       ,SMMACTIVITIES.PROJACTID AS 'Projectactiviteit'
       ,SMMACTIVITIES.RESPONSIBLEEMPLOYEE AS 'VerantwoordelijkeId'
       ,DIRPARTYTABLE.[NAME] AS 'Verantwoordelijke'
       ,CASE SMMACTIVITIES.CATEGORY
              WHEN 0 THEN 'Afspraak'
              WHEN 1 THEN 'Taak'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Actie'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Melding'
       END AS Categorie
       ,CASE SMMACTIVITIES.TASKPRIORITY
              WHEN 0 THEN 'Normaal'
              WHEN 1 THEN 'Laag'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Hoog'
       END AS Prioriteit
       ,HIERARCHYTREETABLE.DATAAREAID
       FROM HIERARCHYTREETABLE
LEFT JOIN cteP
      ON cteP.ELEMENTNUMBER = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.ELEMENTNUMBER
         AND cteP.DATAAREAID = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.DATAAREAID
CROSS Apply (
                SELECT Lvl1 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl3 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
                      ,Lvl4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(50)')
                FROM  ( VALUES (CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS     xml))) B(xDim)
             ) B
LEFT JOIN SMMACTIVITIES
       ON SMMACTIVITIES.RECID = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.REFRECID
       AND SMMACTIVITIES.DATAAREAID = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.DATAAREAID
LEFT JOIN EMPLTABLE
       ON SMMACTIVITIES.RESPONSIBLEEMPLOYEE = EMPLTABLE.EMPLID
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE
       ON DIRPARTYTABLE.PARTYID = EMPLTABLE.PARTYID
       AND DIRPARTYTABLE.DATAAREAID = EMPLTABLE.DATAAREAID
)

INSERT INTO #Tempproj(
       [ProjKey],Lvl1,Lvl2,Lvl3,[Element ID]
       ,Activiteit,Doel,Activiteitsnummer,[Begindatum/-tijd],[Einddatum/-tijd],[Status projectfase]
       ,[Afsluitingsdatum/-tijd],Projectactiviteit,VerantwoordelijkeId
       ,Verantwoordelijke,Categorie,Prioriteit,DataAreaID)

SELECT
       PROJTABLE.PROJID + '-' + PROJTABLE.DATAAREAID AS 'ProjKey'
       ,cteP2.*
FROM CteP2
LEFT JOIN HIERARCHYTREETABLE
       ON HIERARCHYTREETABLE.ELEMENTNUMBER = CteP2.Lvl3
       AND HIERARCHYTREETABLE.DATAAREAID = CteP2.DataAreaId
LEFT JOIN PROJTABLE
       ON PROJTABLE.PROJID = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.[NAME]
       AND PROJTABLE.DATAAREAID = HIERARCHYTREETABLE.DATAAREAID
WHERE Activiteit NOT LIKE 'MLD%'
AND Activiteit NOT LIKE 'O-%'
AND Activiteit NOT LIKE 'OTR%'
AND SUBSTRING(Activiteit, 1, 1) NOT IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
       @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(Activiteit)
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Activiteit FROM #Tempproj
   ) AS B
ORDER BY B.Activiteit

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ProjKey, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(
SELECT T.ProjKey,
        T.Activiteit,
        T.[Begindatum/-tijd]
FROM   #Tempproj T
) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   max([Begindatum/-tijd])
   FOR Activiteit IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY ProjKey'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Then when I run the query, it says that I haven't declared my @Tempproj table yet.

Now I see that I mix up SQL with Dynamic SQL, but I don't know how to fix this giant statement into this.

Any suggestions what I could do here?

EDIT: Table Variable replaced with an actual Temporary Table.

Comment: `@Tempproj` isn't a temporary table, it's a table variable. Don't use as table variable, use a temporary table. Variables can only be accessed in the scope they are declared in, so cannot be access in the dynamic statement.

Comment: OK, good point. I changed the @'s with #'s, but returns the same error unfortunately.

Comment: If it returns the same error (`Must declare the table variable "@Tempproj"`) then you haven't done the repalcements correctly. You don't declare a temporary table, and `@Tempproj` isn't a temporary object.